# Is it possible to create an array of functions that take "inout" parameters in Swift?

Tags: arrays, function, swift

I am running into something that I think might be a bug. Swift lets you create an array of functions, like this:

```
func example1(a: Int) {
    println(a)
}

let functionArray1 = [example1]

println(functionArray1[0](3))      // This prints "3"
```

But if I try to create an array of functions that take an `inout` parameter, I get the dreaded `segmentation fault 11`:

```
func example2(inout a: Int) {
    println(a)
}

let functionArray2 = [example2]  // This produces the seg fault
```

It makes no difference if I actually manipulate `a` inside the function or not.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Is there a way to create an array of functions with an `inout` parameter by using an appropriate type annotation, or some other trick?

EDIT: I have tried providing a type annotation for the array - that does not solve the problem:

```
let functionArray2: [(inout Int) -> ()] = [example2]   // Same error...
```

I have also tried writing the function as a closure (with an explicit type annotation) and then adding the closure to an array, also with no success.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746913/inout-parameter-in-closure-crashes-the-swift-compiler

Comment: They are similar, but in that question you can work around the problem by providing a type annotation for the closure that takes the `inout` parameter, and the project will compile. I have tried getting my example to work by doing the same thing - providing a type annotation for the array that I am trying to create - and it still doesn't work. That is why I'm asking this question - it does not have the same solution as the other question. A question is not a duplicate of another question just because it uses some of the same words...

Comment: I think the issue is more fundamental. This does not crash: `func example2(a: Int) {}; example2` This crashes: `func example2(inout a: Int) {}; example2` So I think we can conclude that `inout` functions as objects are not happy. The array is just a special case of a more general fact.

Comment: That wasn't a very good test, sorry. Here's a better one. In an app (not a playground), try this: `func example2(a: Int) {}; let f2 : Any = example2` It's okay. Now add `inout` and get the segfault on compilation.

Comment: I believe it is a duplicate because the underlying cause is so similar: use of inout in (some sorts of) declarations cause a sig11 with a particular backtrace signature.  Until and unless this issue goes away, the answer is the same: don't do it, or wait until the bug gets fixed.  Your specific use (arrays vs structs) is a minor detail.

Comment: @AlexBrown: Fair enough :) Between your comment and @matt's, I can see that my problem was just an example of a more general problem with using functions that contain `inout` parameters as objects. But hey, I learned something by asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments on the question have pointed out, this does appear to be a bug relating to Swift's handling of `inout` in type signatures for some cases.

Until the bug is addressed, you can work around it by using an `UnsafeMutablePointer`.

```
func increment(a: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) {
    a.memory += 1
}
let functionArray = [increment]

var thing = 2
functionArray2[0](&thing)
println(thing) // 3
```